# SOA suite installation error

Tags: soa

I have installed Weblogic version 10.3.6.0 successfully on my windows system.

When trying to install SOA suite, it fails with the message

> INST-07286: Specified Oracle Middleware home location does not have minimum version 10.3.5.0 of weblogic server. If the version is incorrect then configuring with the Weblogic server will fail.

Not sure why this error comes even though weblogic is installed. Please suggest what could be missing.

I have tried setting the Windows environment variable `MW_HOME` (and restarted the machine) but it does not help.

Comment: Did you download the ZIP distribution pf weblogic? That won't create an Oracle Middleware Home directory

Comment: Yes I did download the zip distribution of weblogic. Is there a way to manually create the Oracle Middleware Home directory ?

Comment: You can try to create a directory c:\oracle\middleware. If that doesn't work I would start over and install the .exe version from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-for-dev-1703574.html

Comment: The C:\Oracle\Middleware directory is already present so that cannot be the problem. I am trying to install SOA suite 11.1.1.7.0, will this work with WLS 10.3.6.0 ? (Or I have to use WLS 10.3.5.0 specifically ?)

Comment: you can download exact version 10.3.5.0 and try.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic server now comes with Jdeveloper in 11g, so there is no need to install weblogic again. I think using 10.X.X version is causing error, please also check with JDK version you are using. I know I am responding too late, but I think this will help if you still didn't resolve it.